# Unable to delete user programmatically in sitecore 9

Tags: user-management

i am trying to delete extranet users through code.
(same functionality that is in user manager)

**Code:**

**User user = User.FromName(username, true);**

**user.Delete();**

i am not getting any error but user is also not getting deleted either.

any suggestions.

thanks,

Comment: how are you passing username? are you adding the domain as well with username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass domain name with a user name like below code :

```
string domainUser = @"domain\user";

if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(domainUser))
{

 Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user =
 Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(domainUser,true);
 user.Delete();

}
```